# Exporting data from Jupyter to Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am new to programming/python and having trouble with exporting my data to excel.
Searched through the internet for a while and couldn't find a good example that suits my case (with a loop).
Can anyone show me how I can export "iteration_count,xn,r" to Excel?

[The code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LDWW.png)

Comment: you need to write it using `openpyxl` or create a dataframe then export it to excel

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pandas dataframe and then do

```
DataFrame.to_excel()
```

Answer (score 0):

like @Umar.H has said, you need to create a dataframe. Add the information you are printing (ie. iteration_count,xn,r) to a dataframe that you instantiate outside of the while loop. After the while loop, you can export the dataframe. You can do this with the command `df.to_csv(r'FileName.csv', index=False)` assuming the dataframe you used is named df.

NOTE: For whatever reason, `.to_excel()` doesn't work in jupyter, but `.to_csv()` works great.

Comment: About [`DataFrame.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) not working, did you run `%pip install openpyxl` or `%pip install xlsxwriter` and set the engine as the referenced documentation and comment by Umar.H advises?